# Fiddler not trapping results from Spring STS

Tags: java, spring, rest, fiddler

Writing an app in Java to consume a restful service.  Getting errors back, so I want to use Fiddler to trap the traffic and see what I am doing wrong.  Fiddler is not trapping results, is there something that I need to do to configure Fiddler, or my IDE (Spring STS)?

Thanks
BR

Answer (score 1):

Most JVMs must be manually configured to proxy their HTTP/HTTPS traffic.

http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-JavaTraffic

`jre  -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888`